# Kohana routing with https/ssl

Tags: php, .htaccess, kohana

I am working on a facebook application and have just set up the SSL certificate but this has caused the routing to stop working.

http://domain.com/tab <- Works but using https causes it to fail

https://domain.com/index.php/tab <- Works

This is currently the code im using in the htaccess file.

```
# Turn on URL rewriting
RewriteEngine On

# Installation directory
RewriteBase /

# Protect application and system files from being viewed
RewriteRule ^(application|modules|system) - [F,L]

# Allow any files or directories that exist to be displayed directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# Rewrite all other URLs to index.php/URL
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT,L]
```

Hopefully someone will be able to shed some light on my problem.

EDIT

Yeah sorry i havnt really put a great deal of information down. When i try going to that link i get returned a 404 "The requested URL /tab was not found on this server". Now i have been told by the client that the server has been set up correctly and apache has AllowOverride.

What other information would someone need to work this out?

Thanks

EDIT

This issue has been solved. The server admins emailed me saying "It looks as though the 443 instance of the site was not picking up the htaccess files properly so I've made a change and reloaded Apache." Simple mistake on their end.

Comment: What does "causes it to fail" mean? Did you setup apache for ssl access? There's not enough information here.

Comment: Im getting a 404 on the page. What information should i provide to help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are just getting a 404, I'd suspect that apache isn't setup for https serving in the same way as http. Check your virtual host directives and make sure they relatively match each other.